# UserControl InputBindings Only working after pressing a button first

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Buttons working fine as expected by clicking them.

**Issue:** When the UserControl is loaded for the first time and i didn't press any button in it, the Keybinds are not working. **After clicking a button** manually the **keybinds do work** as intended. So obviously i would like to let the user use the keybind before any button press :)

(I already tried to set focus on different elements such as the button itself)

*Sample code, of how i setup my commands: (using MVVM-light toolkit)*

**ContextBinding**

```
DataContext="{Binding GameInfoViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

**View**

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Right" Command="{Binding NextCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
//...
<mui:ModernButton Name="ModernButtonNext" IconData="{StaticResource NextIcon}" Command="{Binding NextCommand}" Margin="16 0 0 0" EllipseDiameter="24" IconWidth="14" IconHeight="14" ToolTip="Next image"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private RelayCommand _nextCommand;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the NextCommand.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand NextCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _nextCommand ?? (_nextCommand = new RelayCommand(
            ExecuteNextCommand,
            CanExecuteNextCommand));
    }
}

private void ExecuteNextCommand()
{
    SelectedGameImageIndex += 1;
}

private bool CanExecuteNextCommand()
{
    if (SelectedGameImageIndex >= GameImages.Count - 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: For KeyBinding to work, your window should have focus on it. I doubt window is not in focus.

Comment: @RohitVats my application is a one window application, it loads UserControls as views. Content sits in a grid. if i put a empty button anywhere inside that grid (that is not binded or anything) and i click it the Keybinds do there work.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Like I mentioned in comment, ***control should have keyboard focus so that keyBindings can work on that control***.

> On button click it's working since with that click, userControl has
>   got focus and hence bindings worked after that.

On UserControl load, *put keyboard focus on UserControl so that input bindings can work*. You can put this code in UserControl constructor:

```
    public SampleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Focusable = true;
        Loaded += (s, e) => Keyboard.Focus(this);
    }
```

---

Also that can be achieved via XAML too (key thing is to set Focusable to True on UserControl):

```
<Window FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=userControl}">
   <local:SampleUserControl x:Name="userControl" Focusable="True"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Works perfect! I stuck to much trying to figure it out in the xaml with some things like FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=input}" Thank a bunch.

Comment: Great i will try that approach also